# E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection named "Item" and schema look like

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Item name required"],
      unique: false,
      minLength: [4, "Cannot be less than 4 characters"],
      maxLength: [40, "Cannot be greater then 40 characters"],
    },

    units: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "Item units required"],
      min: [0, "Invalid value"],
    },
    mess: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Mess",
      required: [true, "Mess name required"],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Item", ItemSchema);
```

`Mess` schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MessSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    uppercase: true,
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Mess", MessSchema);
```

and let say i'm inserting data like

```
db.items.insertMany([{
    "title": "chicken qorma",
    "units": 160,
    "mess": "63dde5547cf24f27a81cc82c"
},
{
    "title": "chicken qorma",
    "units": 160,
    "mess": "63dde53a7cf24f27a81cc829"
}])
```

I tried many solutions but nothing is working. I need to duplicate `"title"`.
`"title"` attribute should not be unique but getting an error `"E11000 duplicate key error collection: MessIT.items index: name_1 dup key: { name: null }"`

Comment: What does your schema for `"Mess"` look like?

Comment: const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MessSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      uppercase: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Mess", MessSchema);

Comment: I think the duplicate is `name` in the `Mess` schema.  Maybe you want `sparse: true` for `name`?

Comment: First my Item schema had `unique:true` and then I changed that. But issue was not resolved. I tried `db.Items.dropIndexes()` now error is gone but want to know why it happened. I mean what's the background behind this problem

Comment: To see what duplicate values are in the collection, without the unique index, you could `"$group"` on a field, `"$count"` the number of values, and then `"$match"` on counts greater than 1.